# Why is an example from "Learn C the hard way" showing an error in valgrind?

Tags: c, valgrind

I am trying to learn C and am reading about valgrind. I have a simple C program, shown below, and when I run valgrind it complains about

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value
>
> by 0x100000F50: main (ex5.c:9)
> ==4338==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
> ==4338==    at 0x1001F5BF8: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* This is a comment. */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int distance = 100;

    // this is also a comment
    printf("You are %d miles away.\n", distance);

    return 0;
}
```

Where is the error coming from?

Answer (score 3):

It is common for some implementations of library functions, in order to be most efficient, to skirt some of the rules that valgrind will check.

Notice that the error is in `__vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)`.

This is not always an issue. If there are no side effects (even libraries can have bugs) I would ignore it.

Valgrind often suppresses innocuous library warnings; upgrading might include this one.

Comment: This notably happens on FreeBSD (or used to) when running valgrind without a [suppression file](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) that expresses which errors are ok to ignore. Since the libc used by OS X is based on that of FreeBSD, it's likely that valgrind will experience the same issue, though I have no reference or experience with OS X to indicate that as the actual cause.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any issue in this code. It's fine. Check for the integrity of installed `valgrind` itself. At times, `valgrind` may issue warnings (false positives, as we say), from the code in liked libraries, which are not part of *your* code and mostly out of your control and beyond your concern.

Try checking the code with some other (updated) version of `valgrind`.

BTW, if you don't plan to use command-line argument, you can reduce `main()` to

```
int main(void)
{  ....
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JAL Please let me know how this does not answer the question.

Comment: @JAL and also, to the "supporter" of the comment, more than welcome for some discussion on meta [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298455/3137699).about this.

Comment: @NatashaDutta this is not an answer. you should either explain the message and why it wouldn't be a problem. Or provide means to solve the problem.

Comment: As you want to introduce him to minimizing his code, an empty parameter-list is the same as a single parameter of type `void` *for function definitions*. Also, as he's using C99 (the `//`-comment gives it away), `return 0;` at the end of `main` (and only there) is optional.

Comment: @Deduplicator 1) function signature of `main()` --> `C11`, §5.1.2.2.1. Also, not minimizing the code, it's standard conformance. :-) hope I am not mistaken.

Comment: @NatashaDutta: "... *or equivalent;10)* or in some other implementation-defined manner."

Comment: @Deduplicator that is , ok, see the footnote (10), regarding usage of typedef. related to the second version, rather :-)

Comment: @AymanKhamouma I guess `Check for the integrity of installed valgrind itself.` is enough of a pointer to start digging. We don't know the OP's environment, so technically we can't explain the message OP is getting. We can at most confirm, the problem is not from the code. Oh wait, did you actually read the complete question, at all?

Comment: @NatashaDutta Well I'm sorry, a serious answer should explain the error. or request for more info in comment. Sorry, but you answer is just like asking someone to reboot on the first problem met. this is not an answer.

Comment: @AymanKhamouma 1) don't be sorry for sharing your view, you're more than welcome and Im actually glad you stepped in, other 45+ users who has seen this answer did not bother to do that much. :-) 2) there is no "error" that to be explained, that's what my answer is about 3) a **broken** third-party tool can cause more issues than a reasonable person can explain in a reasonable way. :-)

Comment: @NatashaDutta the probability for his valgrind version to be broken is inferior to the probability that Valgrind is able to raise false positives. (a quick search on google and you'll see it...)

Comment: @NatashaDutta the best way for you to convince me to un-downvote your answer would be to improve it :)

Comment: @AymanKhamouma well, I was already onto it. Just finished. That's all I think I can do. Take your call. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code tested with valgrind 3.10 does not complain about anything. In many cases valgrind upgrade will solve the problem (via package manager or if not available then building yourself should be easy too). I built the code using gcc 4.9.4.

Comment: In this case that's a false positive.